# apache not loading htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal-7

I'm trying to get Apache to recognize the htaccess file at the root of my Drupal website but no matter what settings I try, it is simply ignored. The mod_rewrite module is loaded, AllowOverride is set to All and all paths are correct. The htaccess file has the most basic settings I could find but it doesn't matter because it still doesn't work if I fill it with garbage text. I've scoured the web trying to find answers but nothing has worked yet. Any ideas you may have would be helpful. I'm running CentOS 6.3 with Apache 2.2.15 and Drupal 7.

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

# If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
# directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
# downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F] 

# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 

# Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
# Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

# Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

# Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
 # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
 # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks,
-Dave

Comment: Would you mind posting your actual `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: Yup, just added it, sorry!

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierBourgeois : WAZZZAAAAAAAA